# Unity 2D character keeps playing walking animation when colliding and raycasts don't work as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been working on a 2d top down rpg game and I have added walking animations etc, I want to stop the player from doing a walking animation when they hit a wall and currently I have a box collider with a ray cast, the ray cast originally hit the player box collider when walking down but after using a layermask this has stopped, however while walking left and right work perfectly two issues occur that I cannot seem to fix. First, when walking up or down into a tilemap that is on the collision layer (this tilemap has tilemap collider which will stop the player from walking through them) the animation still plays, and second the player will only collide once instead of repeatedly when hitting the tilemap when two tiles are placed back to back, here is my code for collision, the tiles that are for collision are on layer 6.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Animator ani;
    private bool isMoving;
    private Vector2 lastMove;
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Vector2 movement;
    private LayerMask wallLayer = 1 << 6;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ani = GetComponent<Animator>();
        movement = Vector2.zero;
        isMoving = false;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        isMoving = false;
        movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

        RaycastHit2D ray = Physics2D.Raycast(body.position, movement, 0.6f, wallLayer);
    
        if((movement.x != 0f || movement.y != 0f) && !(ray && ray.collider.tag == "wall")) {
            isMoving = true;
            lastMove = movement;
        }

        ani.SetFloat("MoveX", movement.x);
        ani.SetFloat("MoveY", movement.y);
        ani.SetFloat("LastX", lastMove.x);
        ani.SetFloat("LastY", lastMove.y);
        ani.SetBool("IsMoving", isMoving);
    } 

    void FixedUpdate() {
       body.MovePosition(body.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine.  Most likely, the issue is with your configuration of the AnimatorController.

Do you have transitions in place for (for example) coming from the walk animation back to idle?

Comment: Yeah it all works perfectly with my blend tree, just not the ray cast collision